# How do I use access token from discord oauth2 login to get user information

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token, discord

I have been trying to setup my website so users can login through discord. At the moment, I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            session_start();
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
                {
                    $params = array(
                        'response_type' => 'token',
                        'client_id' => '550631359337594881',
                        'scope' => 'identify'
                    );
                    header('Location:https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/authorize?'.http_build_query($params));
                }
        ?>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which sends the user to the discord authorisation link, and then back to:

```
http://localhost/#access_token=TOKEN&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=604800&scope=identify
```

*I am working on the site through an XAMPP local server so I can use PHP, that's why it is a* `http://localhost`

This is all good, however my issue is that I actually don't know where I am supposed to go from here. I have the token, token type, expiry, and scope, but I don't know how I am supposed to use them.

**WHAT I WANT**

I want to be able to get the user's discord avatar and username, hence why I used the identify scope (more info at https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2). I would like it if it can be done in PHP, because I don't know how to use languages like JSON and AJAX and all that AT ALL, however if it is the only way, its better than nothing.

Can someone please help me follow up after I receive the access token? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As you know PHP you know you can get the Token as a Variable.
With that Token, you can send requests to discords API.
You need the Endpoint which gives you basic user information: `http://discordapp.com/api/users/@me`
For the following, you need the [CURL Libary](https://www.php.net/curl)

```
$curl_h = curl_init('http://discordapp.com/api/users/@me');

curl_setopt($curl_h, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
     'User-Agent: MyCoolAuth v0.1',
     'Authorization: TOKEN'
    )
);
curl_setopt($curl_h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl_h);
```

That reponse is an Array with all Infortmation you could need.
A detailed explanation of its content can be found at [discords developer portal](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object-example-user).

Comment: I don't really understand at all what is going on there, but its not working. 

1. the token is after a hashtag so idk how to use it
2. I dont understand how your code works to modify to work for me
3. I'm assuming $response is what I want to access to see it?

Comment: One question: how did you manage to get the access token?